# How to pass multiple parameters to python function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array with 300 entries. Within each entry is another numpy array [2048 x 2048].

Each entry is a "tiff" entry (in matrix form) which corresponds to the pixel position in a detector. Now, what I want to do is centralize this so that I have an [2048 x 2048] array with each entry having 300 entries corresponding to the pixels from the 300 frames.

I think I have found a way using the `zip` function. But, each time I get back either a [300 x 2048 x 2048] or [2048 x 300 x 2048].

I want a [2048 x 2048 x 300]. I'm trying to do this in a rather economical and pythonic way beyond simply reloading into a new array and reindexing.

```
T_prime = zip(([list(t) for t in zip(*Tiffs)]))
```

Where `Tiffs` is the array as described above.

Comment: The question title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question body.

Comment: I suggest you give a simple and small example

Comment: As @OhadEytan suggests, why not add some code for say numpy array of 3 entries of 4 x 4 sized numpy arrays so we do not have to type them in, and maybe the link between question "title" and "body" becomes clearer after all see the best effort code of yours? Thanks.

Comment: My apologies:  So I load in my numpy array as described above. If I do for example Test = zip (Tiffs[0], Tiffs[1]) I get the solution I'm looking for.  Thus, I wanted a way to pass a bunch of arguments (300 in fact) @OhadEytan

Answer (score 2):

In numpy we often add dimmensions to an array instead of using nested arrays (which is the norm with lists for examples). Once you have all your data in a single array, it's easy to operate on it. In your case it looks like you're looking to transpose the array. An example:

```
import numpy as np
example_data = np.empty(30, dtype=object)
for i in range(30):
    example_data[i] = np.zeros((100, 101))

structured = np.array(list(example_data))

print structured.shape
# (30, 100, 101)
print structured.transpose([1, 2, 0]).shape
# (100, 101, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this way

```
result =  map(lambda x: zip(*x) ,zip(*Tiffs))
```

and here is full example

```
list1 = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]
list2 =  [[5,6,7,8],[5,6,7,8],[5,6,7,8]]
listoflists = [list1,list2]

result =  map(lambda x: zip(*x) ,zip(*listoflists))
print result
```

which will result in

```
[[(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)], [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)], [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)]]
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped! :)

Comment: Great, but did it resolve the issue you were having ?

Answer (score 0):

Would you describe this as an array of 3 items, where each is a 2x4 array?

```
In [300]: Tiffs=np.arange(24).reshape(3,2,4)

In [301]: Tiffs
Out[301]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])

In [302]: Tiffs.shape
Out[302]: (3, 2, 4)
```

If so how about doing a selective transpose?

```
In [304]: Tiffs.transpose(1,2,0)
Out[304]: 
array([[[ 0,  8, 16],
        [ 1,  9, 17],
        [ 2, 10, 18],
        [ 3, 11, 19]],

       [[ 4, 12, 20],
        [ 5, 13, 21],
        [ 6, 14, 22],
        [ 7, 15, 23]]])

In [305]: _.shape
Out[305]: (2, 4, 3)
```

It's still a 3d array, but could be viewed a (2x4) with 3 items each.

Another possibility is that it is really an array of objects, where each object is a 2d array, but I think you'd have had to put some extra effort into constructing it.

```
In [319]: Tiffs
Out[319]: 
array([array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]]),
       array([[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15]]),
       array([[16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23]])], dtype=object)
```

Transposing this is trickier because it really is (3,) array of (2,4) arrays, and axis swapping doesn't cross that `object` boundary.  Something with `zip` is probably required. `zip` can be used to transpose nested lists, but your zip expression are a bit confusing.